# Do High Iron Stores (but within the healthy range) Make Sun Exposure Damage Worse?

Tags: hematology

Ultraviolet damage from sun exposure is related to the creation of free radicals. Iron is often involved in exacerbating damage by free radicals.

Having lower iron stores is associated with reduced risk of diabetes. Could having lower iron stores reduce UV-related damage from sun exposure?

=========================================================================

I add some references after being asked in the comments:

On iron and free radicals: [Iron, Free Radicals, and Oxidative Injury](http://jn.nutrition.org/content/134/11/3171S.full)

UV-light and free radicals: [Ultraviolet light-induced free radical formation in skin](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8127935)

About high ferritin making diabetes worse:
"Compared with those in the lowest quartile, subjects with diabetes in the highest ferritin quartile were 55% (P = 0.029) more likely to have microalbuminuria."
[Source](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23756251)

[Elevated serum ferritin levels predict new-onset type 2 diabetes](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17333112)

Comment: Can you add some references for your claims?

Comment: Chris, I added some references in the question.

Comment: Your references seem to have nothing to do with UV related damage.